# React.js - Both modals close when one was supposed close and the other one open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to close one modal and open the other one, but both keep closing for no reason  and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

My Code

```js
const Modal = ({ closeModal }) => {
  const [ openModal2, setOpenModal2 ] = useState(false)

  const closeModalFunction = () => {
    closeModal(false)
  }

  const openModal2Function = () => {
      closeModalFunction()
      setOpenModal2(true)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='modal'>
        <div className='modal-overlay' onClick={closeModalFunction}></div>
            <div className='open-modal-2'>
                <button className='open-modal-2-button' onClick={openModal2Function}>Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        {openModal2 && <Modal2
            closeModal2={setOpenModal2}
        />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is because your Modal2 is in your Modal1 component so when you close your Modal1, you close your Modal2 functionality as well. You can do this this way

```
    const Parent = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        showModal1: false,
        showModal2: false
    })
    const onCloseModal1 = () => {
        setState(prev => ({...prev, showModal1: false, showModal2: true}))
    }
    const onCloseModal2 = () => {
        setState(prev => ({...prev, showModal2: false}))
    }
    return <>
    {state.showModal1 && <Modal1 onCloseModal1={onCloseModal1} />}
    {state.showModal2 && <Modal2 onCloseModal2={onCloseModal2}/>}
    </>
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't understand how my modal2 is in my modal1 component